# FaunaDB Query Multiple Fields

Tags: faunadb

I am starting a project with faunadb, where users can login using either their email, username or phone number. Is there a way to query fauna for any of those 3 fields submitted by the user?

Comment: create Indexes user_by_email, users_by_username, users_by_phone, from there you can use an Unions for OR operations. make sure those are all unique Indexes, don't want any duplicates for any of those fields. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61509089/how-to-query-by-multiple-conditions-in-faunadb

Comment: Ok, that's what I had in mind. Thanks a lot.